# TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewCtrl' of undefined in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a `Observable.timer` inside a provider that I call from a specific page. I also pass a function to the provider Observable and when it has finished countdown it will call the function located in the initial page. But I get error after timer is ended:

***Note***: I have imported View Controller inside the page but not provider (I get another error if I try to import View Controller inside provider)

**ERROR**

> 1 errors occurred during unsubscription:↵  1) TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'viewCtrl' of undefined

**PAGE**

```
  newTimer() {
    this.countDown = this.timerProvider.newTimer(this.endTimer); //pass function below
  }

  endTimer() {

    const indexModal = self.viewCtrl.index;
    // then we remove it from the navigation stack
    //this.navCtrl.remove(2);

    self.navCtrl.push(WinnersPage, {
      gameId: self.gameId
    }).then(() => {

    });

    console.log('timer ENDED');
  }
```

**PROVIDER**

```
  countDown: any;
  counter = 1*100;
  tick = 1000;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    //console.log('Hello TimerProvider Provider');
  }

  newTimer(endTimer) {
     return Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
      .take(this.counter).map(() => --this.counter)
      .finally(() => endTimer());
  }
```

Comment: Is it still the same error after you use `endTimer.bind(this)`?

Comment: I can not use the this.endTimer.bind(this) because the binding causes the function to fire inside provider when user leaves initial page, the main reason I implemented the timer inside a provider was so the user can go back in the navigation stack and the timer pause or keep going. If user leaves page with .bind() the endTimer() gets fired. The other solution with self global variable seems good but still get error... any idea how to get it to work?

Comment: `bind()` doesn't execute the function. All it does is _return_ a new function that is bound to the provided context. I am not even sure what you are trying to do. But the error in your post should be solved with the bind function. Any other problems you have may be due some problems with other login in your code.

Comment: *logic not login.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use,

```
  newTimer() {
    this.countDown = this.timerProvider.newTimer(this.endTimer.bind(this)); 
  }
```

**Or:**

Since you are calling a `function` from `another function`, the reference of **`this`** is not available inside **`endTimer`** `funciton`

So, assign the `component` `this` to a `global variable self` and use it inside the `endTimer function`

Try this,

```
 let self = this;

  newTimer() {
    this.countDown = this.timerProvider.newTimer(this.endTimer); //pass function below
  }

  endTimer() {

    const indexModal = self.viewCtrl.index;
    if(self.answerModal) {
      self.answerModal.dismiss();
    }
    if(self.hintModal) {
      self.hintModal.dismiss();
    }
    self.navCtrl.push(WinnersPage, {
      gameId: self.gameId
    }).then(() => {

    });

    self.storage.set('firstAnswerCreated', '');
    self.playaudio.pause();

    console.log('timer ENDED');
  }
```

Comment: It's easier to just use `this.endTimer.bind(this)`

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, thnx, I thought of it, but dont know, if I can use that, thnx for the suggestion. I updated the answer

Comment: If I use the first option: (this.endTimer(this)), the endTimer() function gets called immediatley on page load without a timer. If I use the second option I get the same error

Comment: @condo1234, can you paste the complete component?

Comment: @Sravan Just added

Comment: It's supposed to be `this.endTimer.bind(this)`. You missed the `bind` function. See [what it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: I can not use the this.endTimer.bind(this) because the binding causes the function to fire inside provider when user leaves initial page, the main reason I implemented the timer inside a provider was so the user can go back in the navigation stack and the timer pause or keep going. If user leaves page with .bind() the endTimer() gets fired. The other solution with self global variable seems good but still get error... any idea how to get it to work?

Comment: try,  `this.countDown = this.timerProvider.newTimer(this.endTimer(this));`

Comment: `endTimer(self) {}`